# File permission of Log in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.1, with Log set to be generated daily.

I'm heavily using Jobs. Web server is Apache, so therefore PHP is executed as `apache` user, so at the end of the day, a new log file is generated by apache user and file permission is `0644`. I've workers configured via Supervisor, which is being run by apache user. (So far so good)

Now for a random spike in Queue, I've a script setup to run more worker (Consumers of Queue). Problem I'm facing is since Log file is generated with 0644 permission, other users doesn't have write permission to file.

Few solutions I can think of is -

- Start worker from `root` user (can't do, as I don't have permissions)
- A cron to change file permission to `0646` at 00:00:00 each day (also requires root)
- Generate Log file manually at 00:00:00 by current user, so that I would have authority to change permission to `0646` (Can't be reliable, what if `apache` creates it first)
- Start the worker as `apache` user (Since no root, so this is not possible)
- [This Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115631/getting-new-files-to-inherit-group-permissions-on-linux) on Unix SE Site

So my question is what is the best way to do it, it looks like a general problem to me, which any developer could face. Or is there any better way to do this apart from above mentioned methods.

Comment: can't you use the supervisor api to start the worker so it also runs as `apache`?

Comment: I've to run workers occasionally, plus any operation related to supervisor requires sudo (correct me if I'm wrong here)

Comment: `/etc/crontab/` have a field `<user>` which enables to launch the cron with that user

Comment: No, I won't be using cron to run worker. Worker will be executed by a script, which is being run by another user (not `apache`)

Answer (score 1):

> [..] other users doesn't have write permission to file.

Are you sure you want those users to access the file directly? You could just add an API to your laravel app to serve this file (or even only some filtered data from it). This also allows you too have more fine grained access control within your app etc.

Comment: That's a valid point, I guess that limits my options to 4th option only. My problem is I need write permission for other user, from which I might want to run worker.

Comment: if its a logfile, only one app should write to it - your laravel app. Let workers or other stuff use the API or have their own logfiles.